# How do I get GTK based GUI in a Yocto project?

Tags: gtk3, yocto

I am developing a kiosk type application using Yocto and a raspberry pi3.  I have an hdmi touchscreen attached and have a USB keyboard attached for development only. My problem starts when I try to start GTK in one of my processes.

My project involves creating the kernel, has several processes running for various tasks, and will have a touchscreen GUI based on GTK+3 (using Glade).
My kernel is working and my processes are running and able to communicate with each other.  But, now I'm having problems getting any kind of graphical output on the screen.  Right now, all I have is console access as root.
When I start my 'display-mgr' process it tries to start up GTK.  When it tries to 'gtk_init()', I get:
Gtk-WARNING ++: ...timeinfo...: cannot open display:

I've tried the usual 'export DISPLAY' stuff, but it looks like I don't even have the Xserver installed on the board.
I have:
DEPENDS = "libconfig pkgconfig-native gtk+ gtk+3 glib-2.0 libxml2 gnome-common glade"
in the recipe for my process.  I also have: DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " x11" in my image recipe.  Is there some package that I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you start with core-image-sato from poky distro, and gradually replace the pieces. Alternatively, use core-image-weston, which would use that instead of x11.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'll try that approach.  One reason I didn't do that initially is that I want this to be a very minimalistic interface.  I don't want all of the desktop bells and whistles.  I just want the user to interact with a couple of screens and not be able to pop out into a desktop or gain control of the device in any way.  But, I've never worked with Sato.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: By adding 'x11-base x11-sato' (which I found in core-image-sato) to my IMAGE_FEATURES, I am now able to get graphics output in a terminal.  Now, I will try to eliminate as many sato features as I can.  For instance, now I have to open a terminal from the sato desktop.  I want to get rid of the desktop.  If anyone has any pointers for me in that regard, I would appreciate the help.   Thanks, Alexander for pushing me in this direction.

Comment: You should probably look at what packagegroups get installed into the image, I suspect x11 and sato are separate groups. You need the first but not the second.